# Reseting skill points

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I don't know in which one but I was able to buy a book to reset my skill points in another dragon age, are these books available again?

I didn't found anything for it but neither against it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All the blacksmith NPCs sell an amulet that resets all skill points when equipped (to you, or to your companions). The first one costs 1 coin, consecutive ones cost 439 coins. After equipping it, it disappears (it's a single-use item). Be sure to re-equip your old amulet!

You'll encounter your first blacksmith in Haven.

Comment: Oh i didn't notice this...sorry for that and thank you for your answer ^^

Comment: No need to apologize - it's a valid question :)

Comment: Took me ages to actually find the stand at the Blacksmith in Haven where you can buy stuff from! I thought it was later in the game only!

Comment: well then @KyoAkashi, if this is the right answer, you should accept it so others will also know that this question is answered and correctly. ^_^

Comment: i'm sorry again hehe i just forgot ^^'

Comment: Thank you very much. I really needed this. I though after 30 hours I would have to restart.

Comment: I'm in skyhold already, is it still possible to buy the item?

Comment: nvm found it, it's next to the blacksmith in the castle =)